# How to change the navigation bar background in SWIFT IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, background, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to change the navigations bar background image, but i'm getting a fatal error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

```
var image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"Quiz.png")!
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image,
            forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 let logo = UIImage(named: "Quiz.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 38, height: 38))
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```